# Android In-app Billing Error Message

Tags: android, in-app

I was having problems earlier implementing in-app billing for android. I have fixed that issue, but following that is another issue. When I run the application on my phone and another test account phone, I get the error: "This version of the application is not configured for Market billing." I have installed the new version of the app to the Android market as an APK and added the items. When it opens the in-app billing, it shows the name of the item to purchase from the Android market, but gives me the error. When I tried the static example from Google, that worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get this to work you need to sign the package with your release key/certificate, upload to the Market and save it (without activating). Then install the release APK to your device to be able to test. The APK you install on the phone has to have the same version and be signed with the same certificate for IAB testing to work. Details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html).

Comment: Also, when I go back in the market billing section, it crashes my app. I am not completely sure what is causing that.

Comment: Probably a bug in your app. Check the stacktrace and if you can't figure it out, post a new question with the stacktrace and details.